# subprocess for executing unix commands

Tags: python

I basically want to connect to my simulator from there execute few commands.
from unix shell, I connect to my simulator  from unix shell by giving the command "gmake CONFD_NUMBER=1 nthconfdcli", but when I run the below script, my code hangs .

```
def Simulator():
    command = "gmake CONFD_NUMBER=50 nthconfdcli"
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    p.expect("#")
    p.sendline('show test cli');
    p.expect (['#',pexpect.EOF])
    show = p.before      
    print show

    p.sendline('exit');
```

Comment: I guess you are mixing `pexpect` and `subprocess`.It seems you want `pexpect`

Comment: Are you sure it hangs? It should raise an error.

Comment: yes, I basically want expect. but tried opening the simulator command using spawn, but that doesnt seem to work . is there any other way ?

Comment: You need to use `pexpect.Spawn` and then work on the child object

Comment: What happens when you run the simulator without python ? Do you get a prompt for user input ? I would say remove the expect part and test it out to see what happens.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) and you'll examples of how its used.